# Starting Coccinia grandis from ripe fruit

Tags: houseplants, vegetables, germination, vines

I have, at last, laid my hands on a few Coccinia grandis fruits that have ripen on the vine itself.

See the attached image:

[image: Coccinia grandis fruit]

I would love to grow the plant from these seeds.

Is it possible, at all? What is my best shot to be successful --- the most recommended method to start the plant?

I stay in Mumbai, India (tropics) in an apartment on a higher floor. I can place the pot in a window grill that gets adequate sunlight in the morning.

And presently, we have monsoon season (cloudy or clear skies, scattered thunderstorms, temperatures between 25 to 27 deg C --- around 77 deg F)

Please let me know if you need some other information.

Comment: They are ripening quickly now. Do you think it will be a good idea if I drop them in a pot, cover them with soil and water the pot regularly? Or will it be better if I cut them and then put them in a pot? In that case, should I just cut them in half or should I make smaller pieces? Or should I take the seeds out, put them in water overnight and then transfer them to the pot?

Answer (score 1):

From [this website](http://tropical.theferns.info/viewtropical.php?id=Coccinia%20grandis):

> Seed - sow in situ or in containers. When using containers, place 2 - 3 seeds in each pot. The seed usually germinates within 2 - 4 weeks at 20Â°c[164
>   ]. Thin to the best seedling in each pot and grow them on fast, giving occasional liquid feeds. Plant out when 12 - 15cm tall.

Not being personally familiar with this plant, I would suggest that after removing the seeds from the fruit, allow a few to dry in your window for a few days and then plant about 1cm deep in a small well-drained pot. Use store-bought potting soil, not soil collected from the outdoors. Water the pot thoroughly & cover with a transparent material such as plastic wrap or a cut off water bottle until the seeds have sprouted. Move to a larger pot when the plants reach 12 - 15cm.